# Horizontally scrollable div inside full width div

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

[image]
I have a division which horizontally fits the screen inside which I have 5 divisons, I want 4 divisions to appear on screen and 1 division to appear when I scroll the division horizontally. And I want the scrollbar to appear inside the div only and not on the browser window.

Below is my non working code which puts the h1 tag in the left, I want it on the top-left then under it all 5 divs

```css
.outer {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <h1>Header Title</h1>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it with [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox):

```css
.outer {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%; /* doesn't grow nor shrink, initial width set to 25% of the parent's */
  height: 1em; /* just for demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" style="background: red"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background: green"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background: blue"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background: yellow"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background: orange"></div>
</div>
```

Solution with the `h1` element:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <h1>Header Title</h1>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner" style="background:red"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:green"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:blue"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:yellow"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:orange"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've misunderstood you, but I think that what you want to do is have the H1 over the 5 div, like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/p78L2bka/

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Header Title</h1>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner" style="background: red">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="background: green">
    2
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="background: blue">
    3
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="background: yellow">
    4
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="background: orange">
    5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```